# Weight on a specific point

Tags: volume

I have a weight of 27tonnes and it has 6 points of contact with the ground.
The weight is not evenly distributed, so how do I work out how much weight is on each of the 6 points?
I know where the 6 points are and I know how the weight is distributed

Comment: This is a (hairy) statics question. Have you tried considering moments about the points of contact?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't unless you know the unstressed locations of the points and the stiffness of the object.  The problem is overdetermined.  You can think of lowering the object to the ground with a crane, slowly putting more and more force on the contact points.  The shape will deform slightly because of the loads at the contact points and that will transfer the load around.